# Angular 2 load component using 'selector' dynamically

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am facing an issue in angular 2 for load component based on '**selector**' name.

I want to render component in my popup dynamically. Something like this - 
Here is the code:

```
<div>
 <my-selector></my-selector>
</div>
```

I want to render component inside the div.

Comment: Why are you using version 2? Current version is 5.x and it's mostly backward compatible.

Comment: You should add your component.ts file as well as the HTML so that we can see if there is anything wrong there

Comment: @Curiosity_is_Learning i didn't get it

Comment: @ekanojia They mean, when asking a question, you should show code. Nobody can help you with this description.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović is correct you should add files for us to help you , guessing that you are in search for dynamic components , You should check Angular Dynamic components on how to load them

Comment: @Curiosity_is_Learning here is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/RKZWardw73kEOcF50uYX?p=preview

Comment: here is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/RKZWardw73kEOcF50uYX?p=preview . any update?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the question and the plunker mentioned in the comments above.
To make you selector work, you just have to add the Component in your AppModule like this.

```
declarations: [ App, PopupComponent, DynamicComponent ]
```

When you have added the component here, you can use the selector as you want in the App template like this:

```
<button (click)="openPopup()">Launch demo modal</button>
<hr>
<div>
   <my-selector></my-selector>
</div>
<pre>{{closeResult}}</pre>
```

Comment: But i want to load selector dynamically say in one popup i want to load <my-selector></my-selector> in another popup i wan to load <my-selector1></my-selector1> in same html